# each loop to (for loop or while loop)

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Im displaying all the files from **upfiles** array using each loop in jquery,

**CODE using each loop:**

```
$(upfiles).each(function(index3, filelist) {
    alert(filelist.name); //displays filename
    alert(filelist.size); //displays filesize
}
```

**how can I do the same thing using for loop or while loop :**

```
// **CODE I have tried :**
var i;
for(i=0;i<=upfiles.length;i++)
{
   alert(upfiles[i][name]);  // trying this way but not displaying
}
```

Comment: Use `alert(upfiles[i]["name"])` or `alert(upfiles[i].name)`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
for(var i = 0; i < upfiles.length; i++)
{
   alert(upfiles[i].name); // note the removal of the [] brackets
}
```

Special note: when using this `for-loop` you should loop while the variable `i` is less than the length of the array `upfiles.length` and not less or equal, because the array is 0-based, meaning you'll get an `out-of-bound` exception if `i` equals the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the key value as `quoted string` while using [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors),

```
 alert(upfiles[i]['name']);
```

Full code:

```
for(var i=0;i<upfiles.length;i++)
{
   alert(upfiles[i]['name']);
}
```